# How to create a pivot table in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

First question on Stack overflow. I work for a medical testing firm and they need a table that shows how many people in each state received each type of test in 2021. I have all the states in my `adr.state` table and all the test types in my `p.name` table.

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT
    adr.state,
    'TaqPath COVID-19 rRT-PCR Assay',
    'TaqPath COVID-19 rRT-PCR Assay (Saliva Specimen)',
    'TaqPath COVID-19 rRT-PCR Assay (Throat Specimen)',
    'Beckman Access SARS-CoV-2 IgG Test',
    'PSA, Free',
    'Colorectal Cancer Current Risk'
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         r.requisitionNumber,
         adr.state,
         p.name
     FROM
         copia.copia.Requisition AS r
     JOIN
         copia.copia.OrderedPanel AS op ON op.requisitionKey = r.requisitionKey
     JOIN
         copia.copia.panel AS p ON p.panelKey = op.panelKey
     JOIN
         copia.copia.Location AS loc ON loc.locationKey = r.orderingLocationKey
     JOIN
         copia.copia.Address AS adr ON adr.addressKey = loc.addressKey
     WHERE
         copia.dbo.FixDate(r.finalDeliveryStamp) BETWEEN '1/1/2021' AND '4/24/2021'
         AND p.name NOT LIKE '%body mass index%'
         AND p.name NOT LIKE '%hold account%') p 
    PIVOT 
        (SUM(adr.state) 
            FOR p.name IN (['TaqPath COVID-19 rRT-PCR Assay'],
                           ['TaqPath COVID-19 rRT-PCR Assay (Saliva Specimen)'],
                           ['TaqPath COVID-19 rRT-PCR Assay (Throat Specimen)'],
                           ['Beckman Access SARS-CoV-2 IgG Test'],
                           ['PSA, Free'],
                           ['Colorectal Cancer Current Risk'])
        ) AS PVT;
```

What am I doing wrong? I get these errors:

> Msg 107, Level 15, State 1, Line 34
> The column prefix 'adr' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
> The multi-part identifier "adr.state" could not be bound.

In review, what I need is a matrix where the columns are the test names and the rows are each type of state, where the values are the sum of test types that match that state.

Thank you so much!

Comment: you gave your subquery alias of p , adr is not recognized outside of subquery : so `sum(p.state)`

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You should remove the quotes around the pivoted column names both in the `pivot` and in the outer `select`, just use `[]` to quote column names

Answer (score 0):

In your outer query `adr` will not be recognized. Instead use `state` only:

```
SELECT
     state,
    'TaqPath COVID-19 rRT-PCR Assay',
    'TaqPath COVID-19 rRT-PCR Assay (Saliva Specimen)',
    'TaqPath COVID-19 rRT-PCR Assay (Throat Specimen)',
    'Beckman Access SARS-CoV-2 IgG Test',
    'PSA, Free',
    'Colorectal Cancer Current Risk'
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         r.requisitionNumber,
         adr.state,
         p.name
     FROM
         copia.copia.Requisition AS r
     JOIN
         copia.copia.OrderedPanel AS op ON op.requisitionKey = r.requisitionKey
     JOIN
         copia.copia.panel AS p ON p.panelKey = op.panelKey
     JOIN
         copia.copia.Location AS loc ON loc.locationKey = r.orderingLocationKey
     JOIN
         copia.copia.Address AS adr ON adr.addressKey = loc.addressKey
     WHERE
         copia.dbo.FixDate(r.finalDeliveryStamp) BETWEEN '1/1/2021' AND '4/24/2021'
         AND p.name NOT LIKE '%body mass index%'
         AND p.name NOT LIKE '%hold account%') p 
    PIVOT 
        (SUM(adr.state) 
            FOR p.name IN (['TaqPath COVID-19 rRT-PCR Assay'],
                           ['TaqPath COVID-19 rRT-PCR Assay (Saliva Specimen)'],
                           ['TaqPath COVID-19 rRT-PCR Assay (Throat Specimen)'],
                           ['Beckman Access SARS-CoV-2 IgG Test'],
                           ['PSA, Free'],
                           ['Colorectal Cancer Current Risk'])
        ) AS PVT;
```